# Maximizing $f(x,y,z)$ over $\mathcal T=\left\{(x,y,z)\, |\, 0\leq y\leq x-1\, , \, x\in[1,2]\, , \, z\in\mathbb R \right\}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

Maximize
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{|z|\sqrt x}\left|a\left(e^{iz \left(n-\frac12\right)}-e^{iz \left(n-\frac12-y\right)}\right)+b \left(e^{iz \left(n+\frac12\right)}-e^{iz \left(n-\frac12\right)}\right)+c\left(e^{iz \left(n-\frac12+x-y\right)}-e^{iz \left(n+\frac12\right)}\right)\right|$$
subject to
$$\mathcal T=\left\{(x,y,z)\, |\, 0\leq y\leq x-1\, , \, x\in[1,2]\, , \, z\in\mathbb R \right\}$$
where $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$, $n\in\mathbb N$.

In the following I will try to develop at least a partial solution. We can rewrite $f$ as
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt x}\left |a \int_{n-\frac12-y}^{n-\frac12} e^{iz t} dt +b\int_{n-\frac12}^{n+\frac12} e^{iz t} dt+c\int_{n+\frac12}^{n-\frac12+x-y} e^{iz t} dt\right|$$
If $a,b,c>0$, after applying the triangle inequality (which is exact when  $z=0$ because of the sign of a, b and c) we obtain 
$$f(x,y,z)\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt x}\left(a y+ b+c(x-y-1) \right)=g(x,y)$$
Now it is a lot easier to maximize $f$ because we have to find the maximum of the function $(x,y)\to g(x,y)$ in the triangle: $\left\{(x,y)\, |\, 0\leq y\leq x-1\, , \, x\in[1,2]\right\}$.

However, I can't figure out how manage the general case $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a comment. Since $z \in \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 0$ at the maximum point will give $z=h(x,y)$. After which it will be an optimization in triangle region.